# Capture error and continue with sqlcmd :r

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have the following batch file and SQL script that runs several .sql files. Is there a way to log any errors and continue with script?

**myautosql.sql**

```
PRINT 'Starting...'

--:On Error exit

:r SQLQuery10.sql
:r SQLQuery20.sql
:r SQLQuery30.sql


PRINT 'Completed normally on ' + (CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 101))
GO
```

**myautosql.bat**

```
SQLCMD -E -d rstestdb1 -i myautosql.sql
PAUSE
```

When I intentionally `raiseerror` in the SQLQuery20.sql file the batch program stops. Is there a way for it to log the error and continue with script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `raiserror`, the 2nd parameter `severity` dictates whether the query will continue to run or not.  A `severity` of 0-10 are informational (no error is raised), 11-19 are non fatal errors, 20-25 will raise the error and then immediately terminate your connection to the database server.  You must be a `sysadmin` to use a `severity` from 19-25.

I think this simulates what you are trying to do.

### auto.sql

```
PRINT 'Starting...'

:r 1.sql
:r 2.sql

PRINT 'Completed normally on ' + (CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 101))
```

### 1.sql

```
select 1 as value
raiserror ('This will not stop execution', 11, 1)
select 2 as value
```

### 2.sql

```
select 3 as value
raiserror ('This is an information message, not an error', 10, 1)
select 4 as value
```

Then you run the following command to capture the query output to `output.txt` and informational/error messages to `error.txt`:

```
sqlcmd -E -d tempdb -i auto.sql -r1 >output.txt 2>error.txt
```

`-r1` tells `sqlcmd` to redirect informational/error messages to `STDERR`.

`>output.txt` redirects STDOUT from the queries (including affected row counts) to a file called `output.txt`.

`2>error.txt` redirects STDERR to a file called `error.txt`.

Here are the two files from the above script:

### output.txt

```
value      
-----------
          1

(1 rows affected)
value      
-----------
          2

(1 rows affected)
value      
-----------
          3

(1 rows affected)
value      
-----------
          4

(1 rows affected)
```

### error.txt

```
Starting...
Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Server NAME, Line 4
This will not stop execution
This is an information message, not an error
Completed normally on 02/27/2020
```

HTH

Comment: I am not the original poster, so this may not be their intention, but I have a similar need.  In the original environment, I would want SQLQuery20.sql to stop on the RAISERROR, but have the calling script continue with SQLQuery30.sql.  In my case, SQLQuery20.sql is a MASSIVE number of INSERTs, with GOs sprinkled in to control the batch size.  I could put something in a temp table that survives batches and query it for each batch, but just halting the :R and continuing to the next would be easier and more readable.

Comment: @Kevin - You would need to run multiple `sqlcmd` commands from a batch file to do that (one for each SQLQuery##.sql).  Using `raiserror` could terminate the connection for SQLQuery20.sql, and then the batch file would establish a new connection for SQLQuery30.sql.